# Nginx 502 bad gateway for deploying Django Project even it works with uwsgi

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, uwsgi

the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. But I get 502 bad gateway error.

When I check the socket file path I can't see any file.

**/home/bilal/uwsgi/sites/testproject.ini ->**

```
[uwsgi]
home = /home/bilal/my-first-project/venv
chdir = /home/bilal/my-first-project
wsgi-file = /home/bilal/my-first-project/projectname/wsgi.py

socket = /home/bilal/uwsgi/testproject.sock
vacuum = true
chown-socket = bilal:www-data
chmod-socket = 660
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/testproject ->**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <domain> <www.domain>;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/bilal/uwsgi/testproject.sock;
    }
}
```

When I try to connect to server with ip address I get welcome to nginx page because ip isn't written for server_name. But when I try to connect to server with domain I get this error:

*502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)*

I think this problem is about the .sock file but I don't know how can I handle it.

Comment: Did you change server_name <domain> <www.domain> by original domain name?

Comment: yes, I didn't want to publish my domain name here.

Comment: check nginx logs

Comment: Check nginx logs and review the permission of parent directory of socket.

Comment: Did you add domain name in allowed hosts in django settings?

Comment: Did you restart nginx?

Comment: How did you run uwsgi, what the command?

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah how can I check nginx logs?

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan How can I review the permission?

Comment: @VolArt Yes I did.

Comment: How did you run uwsgi?

Comment: @VolArt How should I?

Comment: You need to install uwsgi, then ```uwsgi --ini <path to your file>``` but better to make service.

Comment: @VolArt cd /etc/systemd/system/
sudo nano uwsgi.service

I did this

Comment: May be with systemd like here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Stop your systemd service, try run by hands, and look if it works

Comment: @VolArt yes it works manually

Comment: Still have socket problem.

Comment: Need config of your service config file, path to your project